# Crêpes and crêperies

Tags: vocabulary, cibus

What would be good Latin words for a crêpe and a crêperie?

[Vicipaedia offers *crispa*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crispa) but mentions that the article quality is "maxdubium".
(I find the expression "maxdubium" itself, well, maxdubium.)
The etymologies I found all suggest that the French *crêpe* comes from the Latin adjective *crispus*, but that alone does not imply that *crispus* would be a good translation in any gender.
The closest word for a crêpe that I could find is *libum*, but there could well be a better one.

If *libum* is the food item, then the restaurant would probably be *libarium*.
Whether or not you suggest going with *libum*, how would you derive crêperie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both my English-Latin Dictionaries suggest **Laganum** (plural Lagana).

> Smith: *laganun ex ovo frictum*  [explic. pancake (made with egg) fried.]
>      Ainsworth: *laganum.*

Like "Crêpe" it is a borrowed word:

> λάγανον, τό,      A a thin broad cake, of meal and oil,
>    [Henry George Liddell; Robert Scott [1940]](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.42:2:55.LSJ),

[A cookery site adds:](http://www.cooksinfo.com/laganum)

> It's entirely possible that Laganum evolved into different forms in
>   different parts of the Roman Empire, at different times, and even
>   continued evolving after the fall of official Rome

Vicipǽdia mentions *laganum* briefly on the page for
[***lucunculus***](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucunculus).

But there are no related words for the crêperie or the cook. Perhaps

> Kitchen ***culina*** f. or
>   **Pistor,** baker.
>   **pistrina,** bakery
>   **pistrilla,** a small bakery

Comment: Thanks! I'm now convinced that *laganum* is an excellent translation. I added a second answer about crêperies, although your words for "general bakery" are also often valid.

Answer (score 4):

My dictionary (which I did not have access to when asking the question) also suggests *laganum*, and that word seems indeed very suitable.
I have therefore accepted Hugh's answer.

One can indeed refer to crêperies as small bakeries, but it may not be suitable if clearer connection to crêpes is called for.
My grammar offers three ways to derive nouns from nouns describe places of storage or similar:

1. *-arium*: *aerarium*, *pomarium*, *aquarium*, *herbarium*
2. *-etum*: *dumetum*, *olivetum*, *querquetum*, *vinetum*
3. *-ile*: *bovile*, *ovile*, *suile*

It seems that *-ile* is restricted to animals and *-etum* to plants, so *-arium* is the best choice out of these three.
The numerous other derivative options listed in the grammar seem inapplicable here.

Therefore the best word for crêperie seems to be *laganarium*.
This word seems to exist (mostly in scientific names), but not in the sense of a crêperie.
But it is a reasonable derivation using classical principles and it is intelligible in proper context.